# PhpStorm PHPUnit not stopping on curl_exec

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have one PHPUnit test that calls one API using `curl_exec`. If I set one breaking point inside the test it works, but when I set the breaking point on the API class that is called by `curl_exec` this is not stopping on the breaking point.

My xdebug config:

```
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "/var/www/html/xdebugProfiler"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_port = "9000"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "/var/www/html/xdebugProfiler"
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
xdebug.idekey = "PHPSTORM"
```

I've already put Max simultaneous connections to 10 in my PhpStorm settings.

on curl_exec:

```
        $curl = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE,"XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM");

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT,true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,2);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $requestHeaders[] = "Cache-Control: no-cache";
        $requestHeaders[] = "Pragma: no-cache";
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$requestHeaders);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

I don't know what I can do, to put this to work. :/ Hope somebody can help me on this.

xdebug log:

```
Log opened at 2017-09-28 21:54:12
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
W: Remote address not found, connecting to configured address/port: 192.168.100.113:9000. :-|
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/html/5.4_maintenance/tests/bin/phpunit.phar" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="5.6.19" protocol_version="1.0" appid="7864" idekey="16315"><engine version="2.4.0"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2016 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 4 -n extended_properties -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" status="starting" reason="ok"><error code="3"><message><![CDATA[invalid or missing options]]></message></error></response>

<- status -i 5
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="5" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

<- step_into -i 6
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="6" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/html/5.4_maintenance/tests/bin/phpunit.phar" lineno="3"></xdebug:message></response>

<- breakpoint_set -i 7 -t line -f file:///var/www/html/5.4_maintenance/application/controllers/favoritesController.php -n 15
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="7" id="78640001"></response>

<- stack_get -i 8
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="8"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///var/www/html/5.4_maintenance/tests/bin/phpunit.phar" lineno="3"></stack></response>

<- run -i 9
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="9" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

<- run -i 10
Log closed at 2017-09-28 21:54:16
```

Comment: What xdebug log has to say about it? Does it even tries to connect? IF it does -- does it use the right IP:port?

Comment: I will edit the question with the log

Comment: I noticed that the xdebug is using my local ip address not the server ip address, where can I confure the xdebug to use the server ip address?

If I run the same call on the phpstorm test RESTfull Web Service , the breaking point works

just ran by this tool to compare the ip, and is the same, and one works and the another dont.

Comment: Well -- at very least I see that xdebug has connected to some debug client. Question is -- was that 1st session (PHPUnit debug) or 2nd one (API debug)? In any case -- try placing `xdebug_break();` into your code -- programmatic breakpoint and see how it will behave. Maybe your API file is outside of the project or something?

Comment: *"I noticed that the xdebug is using my local ip address not the server ip address, where can I confure the xdebug to use the server ip address?"* Well ... `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` tells xdebug to detect an IP address automatically. If nothing found -- it uses configured one, which is done via `xdebug.remote_host`. I do not see it in your config .. so it must be an IP that PhpStorm passes via parameters when you launching PHPUnit debug (as it's done in command line/CLI interface) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: I´ve put the xdebug_break(); and still not working :(

Comment: So ... what xdebug log says? Does xdebug even tries to make 2nd connection (when executing API code) or only one (PHPUnit code)?

Comment: I put the log on the question, I cant understand the log for complete, but what I saw there was that xdebug registered the breaking point, but dont even try to stop on the breaking point. 
The only thing I can't understand is if I have:
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1

The Breaking point works when I run curl command line even when I access the api on my cel phone this works, but when I use curl_exec() this don't work. How can this be possible? :(